# Are there any guides for implementing JavaScriptModule in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

Interested in implementing direct **native** to **javascript** calls in react-native. But didn't find any guides for that.

Please, help with some examples of creating and registering native to javascript modules in react native.

---

Already figured out that code from official [native modules android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) documentation has a method named **createJSModules**, which returns a list of **JavaScriptModule** classes.

```
class AnExampleReactPackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  ...

}
```

Javadoc for **com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule** says:

```
/**
 * Interface denoting that a class is the interface to a module with the same name in JS. Calling
 * functions on this interface will result in corresponding methods in JS being called.
 * ...
 */
@DoNotStrip
public interface JavaScriptModule {
}
```

I was able create interface and pass it's class to **createJSModules** but have no idea how to register appropriate javascript module from js code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, after looking into react js sources, I figured out the solution, you need to:

1. Extend JavaScriptModule and pass it to **createJSModules** method of custom react package (e.g. ActionsModule.java).
2. Register that package within you react activity **getPackages** method or directly thought **ReactInstanceManager**
3. Create js file with same name in your js code
4. Register it with **BatchedBridge** as described in listing below.
5. Than after react context initialise, you can get it and call via:

   ActionsModule jsModule = context.getJSModule(ActionsModule.class);
   jsModule.callAction("greet", "hello");

That will call your registered js module method asynchronously.

---

```
// AppPackage.java
public class AppPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Arrays.<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>>asList(
                ActionsModule.class
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}

// ActionsModule.java
public interface ActionsModule extends JavaScriptModule {

    void callAction(String type, String value);

}

// MyReactActivity.java
public class MyReactActivity extends ReactActivity implements ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
        ActionsModule jsModule = context.getJSModule(ActionsModule.class);

        jsModule.callAction("greet", "hello");
    }

    ...

}
```

---

```
// ActionsModule.js
var ActionsModule = {

  callAction(type, value) {
    console.log("callAction => " + type + ":" + value);
  },

}

module.exports = ActionsModule;

// index.android.js
import {
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import App from './components/App';

// js module registration
var BatchedBridge = require('BatchedBridge');
var ActionsModule = require('./ActionsModule');

BatchedBridge.registerCallableModule(
  'ActionsModule',
  ActionsModule
);
//~ js module registration

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

---

UPD> Pushed a demo project to github with a solution for both android and ios: https://github.com/dmba/rct-native2js

Comment: BatchedBridge is undefined if you try import it from the React object.

Comment: Great solution~ Just missing some code in `MyReactActivity`. Please add this code in it.
`@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getReactInstanceManager().addReactInstanceEventListener(this);
}`

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that on iOS? There is no mention of JSModules in neither docs nor headers that I have been looking through. I don't believe it is a one-platform feature.

Comment: @OleksandrYefremov, yep, my friend was able to do that on iOS, will try to upload a working solution for android and iOS on weekend.

Comment: @OleksandrYefremov, I've added a link to github, please have a look.

Comment: @Dmitry. Thanks for posting! That's what our team ended up with as well. The only question remaining is why using `EventEmitter` is the preferred way - it is in the docs and `RCTEventDispatcher` which is basically a wrapper around `RCTBridgeModule` [is deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTEventDispatcher.h#L74-L78). I find `JavaScriptModule` more convenient and less verbose.

Comment: I think it is because react native team want to have a more generic transport between native and js code so that they can easily replace lower level communications with something else and that will not affect already created apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible, but why would you want to do this anyway? Use NativeAppEventEmitter/DeviceEventEmitter and just send it as an event that you'll listen to on the JS side.

Comment: I`m currently using event emitters, but was interested in additional ways of native - js communications, as there are java API that says that you actually can execute interface methods from java through proxy with js implementations.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you get it working, I mostly use observables for this kind of thing. You could try looking at the source code for the event emitters and see where that gets you.